# Why "Pre-oiled Pita"?

Tags: food-science, flatbread, pita

I have started buying Kontos Pre-oiled Pita, and am super pleased with the product.

They taste great and also seem to last forever on the shelf.

.. but I have never heard of "oiling" pitas!  Is this something that is done?  I can not find any references out there for it on google.

Also, what do you think this oiling process is, and does it preserve the pita?

Comment: Wierdly, Kronos doesn't list these as a product on their website: https://kronosfoodscorp.com/product/pita-bread/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is really common to brush a pita with some oil prior to heating for an extra crispy treat. We sort of do that at my house, except be coat the heating device *(a frying pan)* with oil instead of the pita itself.

From [kontos.com](https://www.instacart.com/products/19439885-kronos-original-pre-oiled-pita-10-ct):

> #### Pre-oiled Greatness
>
> Our pre-oiled breads are infused with extra virgin olive oil for flexibility and rich taste.

So pre-oiled pitas have **more flexibility**, so to be **more convenient for wraps**, and pre-oiled pitas have a **richer flavor** and **crisp better** when heated.

Comment: Aha!  Kontos, not Kronos.  OP got the brand name wrong.

Comment: "Infused with" kind of implies the pitas are made without oil, then somehow soaked in oil to "infuse" them. But maybe the oil is just mixed into the dough like a normal ingredient, and "infused with" is BS marketing language.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like the "pre-oiled" label assumes that you're going to be freezing your pitas.

Food Service Direct, which sells frozen Kronos pitas, gives these instructions for preparing Kronos Frozen Original Flat Authentic Pita Bread:

> Preparation instruction: Griddle (Thaw before use) -Pre-heat griddle to 350 degrees F -**Lightly oil each side of pita** -Heat each side for 30 seconds

https://www.foodservicedirect.com/kronos-frozen-original-flat-authentic-pita-bread-6-inch-120-per-case-138177.html

Oiling a frozen pita (or adding oil to the pan) would certainly make it easier to defrost in a pan without burning.

I can't be sure that Kronos assumes, or suggests that you freeze your pitas, but I did find this [Instacart listing](https://www.instacart.com/landing?product_id=1917387&retailer_id=1442&region_id=27925738160&utm_medium=sem_shopping&utm_source=instacart_google&utm_campaign=ad_demand_shopping_rp_kens-market&utm_content=accountid-8145171519_campaignid-11453731439_adgroupid-117541082368_device-c&gclid=CjwKCAiAi_D_BRApEiwASslbJ3-mz8P-tdNWZcRgHp3_BHuTsdvIijxIXPNm7i3DFvxPMvi-Mu95kRoC-BIQAvD_BwE) for Kronos pre-oiled "gyro bread," which includes these instructions:

> Warm in oven, microwave or on grill.
>
> Keep frozen for maximum freshness.

I'd guess that those instructions come from the packaging, rather than from the seller.

Answer (score 0):

This oiled pita is not getting flaky even days past w/c is ideal for stuffing and rolling it w/o breaking the bread.